# Why is this happening when I bake physics to keyframes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, keyframes

So, I'm trying to do some stuff with physics and cell-fracture, and I need motion blur. When I bake the physics and render w/ motion blur, the objets aren't in the scene. So I tried baking the physics to keyframes, and this happened.

[image: THIS IS NO LONGER A WALL]

Does anybody know how to fix this? I really need motion blur in this scene.

Also, the objects were keyframed a little bit. The animation was keyframed, and it seems that that's the problem. But I don't know any other way to make the wall not move for a certain amount of time.

Blender 2.72

Comment: It may take more information to solve this issue, uploading your .blend to pasteall.org/blend and posting the link here would help tremendously.

Comment: @Brennan, how exactly did you keyframe it, like just keyframing the checkbox from 'animated' at the rigid body settings?

Comment: @RayMairlot Wow, that's an oldie :) 2015!! Hard to believe it's been 3 years. And yes, we now prefer to have files uploaded there instead.

Comment: @VRM Sorry. The question was in the review queue. I didn't realise it was an old question.